# TypeError: ("x() got an unexpected keyword argument 'result_type'", 'occurred at index 1'), pandas 0.23.4

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting a Type error using the result_type keyword applying a function to a dataframe in order to add 2 columns.

I can see the usual cause of this is due to a pandas version, but I have 0.23.4 running and am receiving this error.

```
def parse_allocation(x):
direction = {'En':'entry',
                 'Ex':'exit'}
point = x['Name'].split(' ')
if len(point) > 4:
    curvename = 'Allocation.' + point[2] + ' ' + point[3] + '.' +  direction[point[1]]   
else: 
   curvename = 'Allocation.' + point[2] + '.' +  direction[point[1]]
   
ent_ex = direction[point[1]]  

return curvename, ent_ex


 df_allocation[['curvename', 'DirectionKey']] = df_allocation.apply(parse_allocation, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

This works fine on my local env which also is using `pandas 0.23.4` which seems odd.

any ideas?

Error:

```
TypeError: ("parse_allocation() got an unexpected keyword argument 
'result_type'", 'occurred at index 1')
```

thanks

Comment: pandas treats the parameter `result_type='expand` is a parameter for the custom function `parse_allocation` rather than parameter of the `apply()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because pandas treats the parameter `result_type='expand'` as a parameter for the custom function `parse_allocation` rather than parameter of the `apply()` function.  You can solve it by using lambda function as follows:

```
df_allocation[['curvename', 'DirectionKey']] = df_allocation.apply(lambda x: parse_allocation(x), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Comment: That seems to fail for the same reason too TypeError: ("<lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'result_type'", 'occurred at index 156899').  I made a work around using `df_allocation[['curvename', 'DirectionKey']] = pd.DataFrame((df_allocation.apply(lambda x: parse_allocation(x), axis=1)).tolist(), index=df_allocation.index)`.                                  
There must be something amis with my pandas installation I think.

Comment: @Jman88  That's weird.  I encountered the same problem before and used the same to solve it.  Can you please post some sample data to reconstruct the error case ?

Comment: I think the issue is my pandas there seems to be pip 0.23.4 whilst conda is 0.22.0 (which is causing the issue)

Comment: @Jman88  That's great you find the root cause. Another case of versioning problem then.